# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse always returning "The operation has timed out"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, http

I would like to get the HTML data from specific website **("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Silver-Oak-Service-Apartments-Next-to-Vivek-Showroom-Selaiyur/044PXX44-XX44-111215152228-W2G5_BZDET?xid=Q2hlbm5haSBIb3RlbHM=")**

***Interesting part is,*** I can able to get the data for other websites like (Google, StackOverFlow, etc)

I'm using below code, But I'm receiving **"The operation has timed out"** always.

```
public static string GetPageData(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 7000;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,fr-CA,it-IT;q=0.6");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
                httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://justdial.com"), new CookieCollection());
                httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;

                httpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 200;
                httpWebRequest.Timeout = 7000;
             
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream == null)
                        return string.Empty;

                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                    string end = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    streamReader.Close();
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                    responseStream.Close();
                    responseStream.Dispose();
                    response.Close();
                    return end;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the address you posted here in a WebBrowser? What happens? -- Unrelated: you have a lot o redundant settings there, the Timeout is way less than the default, but it may be intentional. This: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;` you need to set to `false`, your code is not handling the `true` consequences.

Comment: I can able to open in a browser. It works fine. I have tried with ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 
no luck

Comment: Well, I cannot open it, it errors out after a while. Maybe you posted (or using in code) a non working address? -- The `Expect100Continue` thing, as you can read in that comment, is *unrelated to the current issue*. It's just an FYI.

Comment: @Jimi, 
Please try to open "https://www.justdial.com" first then try the actual URL. I'm suspecting its might because of Cookies. 

How to I get the cookies and send dynamically .

Comment: The address you have posted here is truncated. It's much longer than that. If you're using the address as presented here, it will time out.

Comment: Forgot to mention: that site (as many others) has anti-bot scripts (expects a response from a WebBrowser and the default access action is `navigate`). If you try to fake a UserAgent, it will wait for the Browser response, then eventually timeout (usually, a 504 StatusCode). If you declare yourself as a Bot, adding the `bot` keyword to the User-Agent (e.g., `Mozilla/5.0 bot (...)`), you should get a 403 StatusCode immediately. -- You should probably use a head-less WebBrowser to navigate to that site, then get the rendered HTML, if that's what you're after.